# Manual inserted rows are not fetched through JDBC in Vertica

Tags: java, jdbc, vertica

I have created the table 'my_table' manually in Vertica using 
`create table my_table(c1 int);` and inserted the data into that table using 
`insert into my_table valUES (1);`
so my table now results in

```
select * from my_table;
 c1 
----
  1
(1 row)
```

I'm using Vertica JDBC driver to fetch records from Vertica, but my result set is empty, code is shown below.

```
  protected static final String VERTICA_DATABASE = "my_db";
  protected static final String VERTICA_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
  protected static final String VERTICA_PORT = "5433";
  protected static final String VERTICA_USER = "dbadmin";
  protected static final String VERTICA_PASSWORD = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.vertica.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:vertica://" + VERTICA_HOST + ":" + VERTICA_PORT + "/" + VERTICA_DATABASE
        + "?tcpKeepAlive=true";
    Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(url, VERTICA_USER, VERTICA_PASSWORD);

    // fetching
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from my_table;");
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while(resultSet.next()) {
      System.out.println("we are here : " + resultSet.getInt(1));
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is it related to table row access?

NOTE: if I try to insert row in Vertica using JDBC and after that if I try to fetch records using JDBC only that inserted record is coming under result set and the row which was manually inserted is not fetched under result set.

Comment: Did you commit the data after you manually inserted it? Are you sure you're connecting to the same database?

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue now. The Data in the Vertica was not committed once I tried committing the data in Vertica using ```commit;``` JDBC is now picking up that record